# Having a SCSS Mixin problem with variables

Tags: sass, mixins

I have a bunch of core colors

```
$blue : blue;
$green: green;
$red: red;
```

I need to make tint of all of them like this

```
$blue-80: lighten($blue, 20%);
$blue-60: lighten($blue, 40%);
$blue-40: lighten($blue, 60%);
$blue-20: lighten($blue, 80%);
```

I am trying to create a @mixin that will do that for me. Something like

```
@mixin tint($color) {
   ${$color}: lighten($color, 20%); 'and then the rest'
 }
```

so then I can use $blue-80 some where else like

```
.blue-80-border {
   border-color: $blue-80;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sass have no support for dynamic variables reference. However you can use `@function` instead of `@mixin` to achieve your goal:

```
@function tint($color, $amount: 20%) {
   @return lighten($color, $amount);
}
```

However it doesn't look much different from native Sass color management functions so it may be worth to use them instead.

Moreover your tint calculations may be wrong, please refer [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/tint-shade-functions/), it proposes different solution for tint calculation. I prefer use of slightly modified version that allows more convenient argument usage:

```
@function tint($color, $percentage) {
    @return mix(white, $color, 100% - $percentage);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically create variables using Sass, but you can create selectors.

```sass
$blue: blue;
$green: green;
$red: red;

@each $color in $blue, $green, $red {
  $i: 90;

  @while 0 < $i {
    #{$color}-#{$i} {
      color: mix(white, $color, $i);
    }
    $i: $i - 10;
  }
}
```

[You can see the output here](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e810dc26155f1eaa764ee8cb645a5224)

If you still want to use variables, you may want to consider using Sass maps or CSS variables.